# conditional stage is not executed in travis

Tags: travis-ci

I've got a simple stage configuration

```
env:
  global:
    - BUILD_TYPE=demo
    - EXECUTABLE=false
if: env(EXECUTABLE) = false
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: stage_exec_1
      if: env(BUILD_TYPE) IN (demo, production)
    - stage: stage_exec_2
      if: sender = lapots
    - stage: stage_not_exec
      if: (NOT branch = master)
```

But the stage `stage_exec_1` is not executed. My `BUILD_TYPE` variable is set to `demo` so it should execute `stage_exec_1`. But it doesn't happen.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

neither `if:` nor `jobs:` are valid values in `.travis.yml` so they're just discarded. Travis is pretty liberal about silently dropping things it doesn't know what to do with. Specifying behavior in `env:` is fine, but move the logic into a `script:` block and execute your if-statements there, or even from a script that the `.travis.yml` calls.

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Implementing-Complex-Build-Steps

Comment: the problem is that `stage_exec_2` is executed